# Background color is stuck after changing it to transparent

Tags: html, css, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

So I am using a plugin (https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview) or (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera-preview/) and for it to be shown, I have to set the background color to transparent like so in camera.scss:

```css
    page-camera {

}
html, body, ion-app, ion-content, ion-page, .nav-decor{
   background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

But an issue I have is that when I close the cameraPreview and pop the view, my background is stuck as transparent.

How can I get my background to only be transparent when I am using the camera plugin?

Here are some screenshots:
[image: Background is white here]

Background is white in this image ^^ correct
[image]

Background is transparent in this image ^^ correct
[image]
Background is transparent now ^^ incorrect

I have no other css being used in the app, so how can I change the background-color only on the one camera screen?

Thanks

Comment: you can use `background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.0);` i  thing it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use your transparent part inside the page-camera?

```
page-camera {
  html, body, ion-app, ion-content, ion-page, .nav-decor{
      background-color: transparent !important;
  }
}
```

So it only effects to that page only. Or you have to set the **background-color:initial** in your home.component(If there is any).